# Export to CSV using for each PHP

Tags: php, api

I'm currently using an API to fetch the mobile operator for my SMS leads. I already have code which makes an API request to the service to fetch the mobile operator which works fine when I use it with a single input field. However, now I want to implement with a textarea where there is a phone number after each comma and it exports the numbers in one column and corresponding operators in another column.

Phone number format is UK:

```
+447000000000
```

API Documentation:
[numverify.com/documentation](http://numverify.com/documentation)

How can I export all results to a CSV or Excel file in the format of:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|phone number 1 here  | mobile operator for phone number 1 here |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|phone number 2 here  | mobile operator for phone number 2 here |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|phone number 3 here  | mobile operator for phone number 3 here |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Current code:

```
<?php

// set API Access Key
$access_key = 'myapikeyhere';

if(isset($_POST['check'])){
    // set phone number
    $phone_numbers = explode(",", $_POST['numbers']);


    foreach($phone_numbers as $key=>$phone_number) {
        // Initialize CURL:
        $ch = curl_init('http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key='.$access_key.'&number='.$phone_number.'');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Store the data:
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode JSON response:
        $validationResult = json_decode($json, true);

        // Access and use your preferred validation result objects
        // $validity = $validationResult['valid'];
        // $country_code = $validationResult['country_code'];
        $carrier = $validationResult['carrier'];
    }

}

?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea rows="40" cols="20" name="numbers"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="check">Check</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Which API is it? Could you tag it with the correct API? The general tag is off-topic

Comment: *"Which API is it?"* i assume https://numverify.com/documentation ?  @Dharman

Comment: Yes it is numverify.com/documentation

Comment: *"Optional parameters:

country_code     specify a country code if you intend to 
                 use a national phone number for your request"*  ... pretty sure your phone format is wrong which you are posting.

Comment: I only need to store the network operator and phone number.

Comment: Yes but if you send `51111` (asumming this as valid phonenumber) for example there API don't know in which country they need to look it up? As the number might exists in more countries??

Comment: All of the phone numbers i have are valid UK numbers starting with +44.

Comment: you want only export mobile number and operator in csv right?

Comment: could u hire me in freelancer

Comment: You are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php - open the file, in your loop call fputcsv for each line, then close the file when you're done.

Comment: Bro freelancer may be block your account thats why your payment is reverse from my account balance